# execution time handling for functions in a loop

Tags: php, foreach, execution-time

Im facing some issues with a longrunning loop.
It goes through around 40.000 urls that it scrapes. however, some external pages can be unreachable at that exact time etc.

If it throws maximum execution time, the whole function stops. so im at a loss of how to go around that.

been scourging the net for answers and found how to catch the timeout exception. so did a function like this :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',15 ); 
function shutdown() 
 { 
     $a=error_get_last(); 
     if($a==null)   
         DoMyStuff();
     else 
         DoMyStuff(); 
 } 
register_shutdown_function('shutdown'); 

foreach blabla {
    shutdown();
}
```

My thoughts is that it will catch a timeout, and give it another attempt if it does.
But that's not really good enough.

Optimally i would want a script that tries to do my function 3 times and if it times out 3 times- then go on to next in loop. 
but i cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated SO! =)

Comment: well, use a try and catch statement. You can also use a `@` before the function or a variable call to supress errors

Comment: would `@` just suppress errors from showing or would it actually ignore it and move on to next in loop? will check out try and catch.

Comment: Having a max execution time of 15 seconds probably isn't helping. You might look into using CURL - let it try 3 times, if it fails, move on to the next url. http://www.sitepoint.com/using-curl-for-remote-requests/ could be helpful for you.

Comment: You should not implement such time consuming and unpredictable things in a single php script which you even run via a browser/http server combination considering that you face a problem with the maximum execution time. Either use php as `cli` language or implement a queuing system that executes the scraping jobs in separate script runs.

Comment: @Bryan - My question is kinda how to do that 3 times then move on to next url.. im using simple_html_dom, even if i switch to curl i would still have to know how to execute 3 times and move to next. 15 secs  can easily be upped

Comment: curl returns false on failure. after 3 failures, move on. just use a counter variable to count the failures.

Comment: I assume you're using `file_get_contents` now to pull back the page contents?

Comment: its a combination i think.. using this here : [ultimate web scraper toolkit](https://barebonescms.com/documentation/ultimate_web_scraper_toolkit/)